# Email git changes using Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline that has two git repos attached to it, call then `git.github.com/userbar/repo1` and `git.github.com/userfoo/repo2`. I have it so right now in the Jenkins script that the final action is that it emails me a message with 'foobar please fix me' in it.

This is what I have right now (well parts of it)

```
finally {
    DEFAULT_SUBJECT="project Blah Build: #${BUILD_NUMBER} - ${currentBuild.result}"
    BODY="Commits made to project Blah:\n\n"
    mail to: 'josh.kirby@wysdom.ai',
    subject: "${DEFAULT_SUBJECT}",
    body: "${BODY}"
}
```

Comment: are you saying ${BUILD_NUMBER} - ${currentBuild.result} doesnt work?

Comment: @metalisticpain No sorry it works, I updated the post with what I figured out and I forgot to go back and correct the wording.

Comment: no worries, you should answer your own question and accept it :)
https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: See this for change log https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217630098-How-to-access-Changelogs-in-a-Pipeline-Job-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the build number and status, no idea on the git changes

`DEFAULT_SUBJECT="project Blah Build: #${BUILD_NUMBER} - ${currentBuild.result}"`